# How to make software features more visible to users?

Tags: usability

We have released a beta version of our software, and as we talked to people who started using it, we have found that a lot of the features (which we thought were essential) were not known and not used by the users.

What are the possible ways to inform the application users about the features of the application? I personally find the "Tip of the day" popups extremely annoying and disable them quickly. Are there better ways?

Comment: This question is more suited to the [User Interface site](http://ui.stackexchange.com/), but I'm fairly sure that it (or something very much like it) as already been asked over there. Indeed - http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/discovering-new-features

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that site and the question. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the: features, application, platform and users.

There is no magic usability dial that you can just turn or button you can just push.

Even within the above there may be multiple ways that a feature can be made more discoverable but it the right one(s?) may be dependent upon how much flexibility you have. In that you've just released the app to actual users, I'm guessing that you're not in a position to restructure the app or make dramatic changes to the way it is architected to improve discoverablity.

This is why usablity testing (with real users) should be started early (in the development process) and done often.

If you can provide a more specific example of a feature that you want to make more discoverable then you may get a more sepcific answer. And if you ask it at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ you may get a better answer still.

Comment: We have the flexibility. We can make dramatic changes if we feel that they will have dramatic impact. I am looking at http://ui.stackexchange.com/ now, and probably try to ask there

Answer (score 0):

- Issue a "changelog" with new releases, that will show as part of the installer wizard in a "readme"-type dialog.
- Yes, tips of the day can be annoying and are often turned off, but try a one-time dialog when the newly-updated program starts, with a summary of new features.
- Extensive help documentation, including a series of "How Do I" articles.
- Use icons with ToolTips to attract attention to new menu options/buttons/features in the first version they're released.

People often seem dead-set against learning the software they use on a daily basis. Most office-type jobs require regular use of MS Office, but I doubt very many could even tell you how to create an Excel chart without fumbling their way through it while doing so. The best you can do is make the learning resources available.